# Can't run a portion of PHP after hitting a submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

having some issues with PHP.

I've written some code using PHP's mail() function- I've tested it out and it sends properly. (tested it by not using an if statement, it just ran on refresh).

I then created a form (email,phone,message etc) with a submit button.

Put the PHP email function in an if statement (I've tried the following if statements to check if the forms have been submitted:
if(isset($_POST)){
if($_POST)
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
err, and a few others I found on here but they all basically check if anything has been submitted through post.

Here's the code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


//BEGIN EMAIL FUNCTION

//headers
$additional_headers[] = 'From: no-reply@<my website went here>';
$additional_headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$additional_headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
//end headers


$to = '<my email here>';
$subject = "[Contact Form Message] " . $name;
$bodymessage = '
<html>
    >LENGTHY HTML HERE, no need to see that. Completely irrelevant to everything else<
</html>

';


mail($to, $subject, $bodymessage, implode("\r\n", $additional_headers).  $additional_parameters);
$feedback = 'Message Sent.';}
```

and then I have the HTML here:

```
<div class="contact-form">
<p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
<form action="?" methods="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Recpient:</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" value="Contractor"/>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name here"/>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Email:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" />
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Phone:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here" />
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="42" rows="9" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your full message here. Feel free to ask any question or send any of your inquiries through here."></textarea>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

So how exactly can I send the email (with the aforementioned variables) upon submitting? I'll answer any questions you've got for me that might help.

Comment: Proper `<form>` attribute is `method`, not `methods`

Comment: oh my god...
if this works i might contemplate suicide

EDIT: IT WORKED! THANK YOU!

Comment: And why do you have a question mark in the `action` of form?

Comment: @csabinho followed a guide for the mail() function and how to use it, in the exmaple they give that was what they had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit methods="post" to method="post" bro.

Comment: yeah, someone commented on the op.

was really frustrated for a bit... woops lol

Comment: haha Everybody has a wrong time.Dont worry bro :))